# how to click on the plus symbol using selenium only if the plus symbol is there and extract the row

Tags: selenium

https://www.screener.in/company/GRANULES/consolidated/

in the following link how to click on the plus symbol using selenium only if the plus symbol is there and extract the row  [this is the  image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwOog.png)

and also how to extract specific tables from the given link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elems=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//section[@id='balance-sheet']//button[./span[.='+']]")
for elem in elems:
    elem.click()
```

This should get all the buttons to click and click them.

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: is there any method to extract tables with different id's at once

Comment: Not at once but you could use pandas.read_html() to read entire tables.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I have the exact same problem. This code throws me a syntax error

Comment: Ok let me update it. It should now work without depreciation and syntax errors now.